# Query VM maximum cpu utilization from Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

I'm running following query to get vm cpu average from past 30 days.

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == "Processor" and Name == "UtilizationPercentage"
| where _ResourceId contains "resourcegroups"
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(Val) by Computer
```

Now I would be interested in querying maximum cpu utilization instead of average because workloads might need a lot of resources for a short time and result into a low average. Averages are also sneaky and hide undesirable behavior.

I have came up with these two but don't know if they are done right or are they showing data right.

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == "Processor" and Name == "UtilizationPercentage"
| where _ResourceId contains "resourcegroups"
| summarize percentiles(Val, 99) by Computer
```

and

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == "Processor" and Name == "UtilizationPercentage"
| where _ResourceId contains "resourcegroups"
| summarize AggregatedValue = max(Val) by Computer
```

Purpose of doing this is for re-sizing vms. Any tips how I could achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your queries are correct (KQL-wise): one will return the 99th percentile, and one will return the max. As for which one better suits your needs - only you can tell.

Comment: Now when using query | summarize AggregatedValue = max(Val) by Computer almost all my computers has max value of 100% (data are generated every 60 sec).  Is is possible somehow query max(Val) by Computer but so that I would summarize data points by one hour / 30 mins which would probably degrees computers that has value of 100%. Now it means that  if vm has one gone to 100% 1 time in past 30 days for 1 minute it show as 100% which do not really pretend real scenarios or is not relevant. Relevant would be if servers workload normally spikes e.g to 70% for 30mins and then drops to 10%.

Comment: So maybe somehow using by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
 but then grouping all results to one row instead of getting 5000 rows of data because   bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)